# How do I access response headers using HttpClient in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have written an authentication service in Angular 5 which does a POST request to my backend using the HttpClient class. The backend responds by sending a JWT bearer token.

My request looks like this:

```
return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/login', {
  'username': username,
  'password': password
}, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
})
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  });
```

}

How do I access the authorization header of the response?

When I write the response to the console, like above, it says 'null'. I know the error is  not in the backend because I captured the traffic and the backend is indeed sending the bearer token.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To access the full response (not just the body of the response), you must pass the `observe: 'response'` parameter option in your http request. Now you can access the headers with `res.headers`

```
return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/login', {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    }, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders()
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
        observe: 'response'
    })
    .map(res => {
        let myHeader = res.headers.get('my-header');
    });
```

[Docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

Comment: how can i doit in a get request?