# Making a empty get XMLHttpRequest to http://www.googleapis.com and unable to assign response header value to a global variable

Tags: angular, angular5

I am making a empty get XMLHttpRequest to http://www.googleapis.com and getting current date and time from its headers. I got this technique from a website which works absolutely fine and prints accurate date and time. But I am having difficulties in assigning the dateTime value to a global variable.

Error: Property 'dateTime' does not exist on type 'XMLHttpRequest'.

Please suggest me any way to assign this value to `this.dateTime` variable or how can I do this with angular's own Http functionality.

**(Code from component.ts file)**

```
dateTime: any;

  getDateTime(){
    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let dateTime;
    xmlhttp.open("HEAD", "http://www.googleapis.com", true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        dateTime = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader("Date");
        console.log('Time date from Google:', dateTime); //gives accurate date and time
        this.dateTime = dateTime; // Error: Property 'dateTime' does not exist on type 'XMLHttpRequest'.
        return dateTime;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Comment: .. why are you using xmlhttprequest? you generally use `@angular/common/http`

Comment: @SurajRao I am new to angular. I have used http before but don't know how to access header using http. Please help me if you know this.

Comment: you should go through the documentation/ tutorial. In any case use arrow function here. Instead of `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {` Try `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = ()=> {};` But its a bad idea. Read https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @SurajRao I think you didn't get my issue. I know how to make get and put requests using angular http. The issue is I am making empty get request to a url. It is giving a response and I want to access its headers. I don't know how to access headers using angular http thats why I am using XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47753885/how-do-i-access-response-headers-using-httpclient-in-angular-5?rq=1 does this help?

Comment: @SurajRao I am making a get request and in this question he is making a post request.

Comment: doesnt matter same way https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response docs

Comment: Please write a complete answer so that I can follow it.

Comment: @HDJEMAI Who the hell is asking to make a post request here? :/